# Registry.SetValue not working for x86

Tags: c#, .net, windows, registry

I want to edit a specific value (type `REG_SZ`) in the registry for both, x64 and x86, but the SetValue method does not change the value for x86. The x64 works fine. This is my code:

```
RegistryKey regKeySpecific = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(
                                   RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32);

RegistryKey registryKey = regKeySpecific.OpenSubKey(
    "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\FolderDescriptions\\{B4BFCC3A-DB2C-424C-B029-7FE99A87C641}\\PropertyBag", true);

registryKey.SetValue("ThisPCPolicy", "Show", RegistryValueKind.String);

registryKey.Close();
```

I'm using the `RegistryView.Registry32` parameter in the first code line to change the value in x86 registry, but this is not working.

The problem is identified, but not solved. This code changes always the key in the x64 (WOW6432Node) registry:

```
"SOFTWARE\\WOW6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\FolderDescriptions\\{B4BFCC3A-DB2C-424C-B029-7FE99A87C641}\\PropertyBag"
```

Comment: @HansPassant Have a look on my code. I'm using  RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey or is that wrong?

Comment: Okay, why are you using Registry32 when you meant Registry64?  Explorer is a 64-bit program.  Best way to do this is to just allow your program to run in 64-bit mode as well.  Right-click your EXE project > Properties > Compile tab > Platform target = AnyCPU and Prefer 32-bit unticked.

Comment: That's right. But I want to remove the ThisPC folders from the explorer. If you are using a x86 application like Notepad++ and open a document, the folders already exists. Therefore I have to edit the keys from the x64 and the x86 location

Comment: It works just fine when I try it, using RegistryView.Registry32 reliably updates the Wow6432Node version of the key, regardless of the bitness of the process   Tested on Win10.  Behavior for this key is not specified in [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384253(v=vs.85).aspx) so there is no *expected* behavior.  You have to document your Windows version.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You evidently have a program executing in x86 (32-bit) mode.  Windows x64 performs registry redirection for 32-bit applications, so that trying to access

`SOFTWARE\Microsoft`

will instead access

`SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft`

The `Registry32` flag makes this same redirection available to .NET applications running as x64.  It has no effect for you, because the OS already turned on that redirection.

To access `SOFTWARE\Microsoft` on a 64-bit OS from a 32-bit process, you should use the `Registry64` flag which disables the redirection.

Remember (your question has this backwards)

- `SOFTWARE\` is the native registry, 64-bit on a 64-bit OS
- `SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\` is the 32-bit compatibility registry on a 64-bit OS

WOW64 is not the layer that provides 64-bit support.  It is the layer that provides 32-bit application support when the OS is 64-bit.  It means "(Support for) Windows (32) On Windows64".